# Add elements in master page from the content page

Tags: html, asp.net

i have a master page like this:

```
<div style="position: relative;display:flex; left: 30px; top: 20px;height:100%; float: left; width:95%"> 
      <div style="float: left;font-size: 12px;height:100%; width: 90%;">
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">                                         
                        
         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       </div>                
       <div runat="server" id="div_Basket" style="float: right; font-size: 12px;height:100%;min-width:180px;width:180px;">
       </div>
</div>
```

the page is divided keeping on right a menù.
on one content page i would add a element on the right side.
how can i do it?

Comment: There is no need for the image - it does absolutely nothing to help the question, and if anything makes it a lot worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you need to add another `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` within the second `<div>`...

```
<div runat="server" id="div_Basket" style="float: right; font-size: 12px;height:100%;min-width:180px;width:180px;">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="BasketPlaceHolder" />
</div>
```

Then within the page you wish to add the new element, implement a corresponding `<asp:Content>` element...

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="BasketPlaceHolder">
  <div id="newElement"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

The advantage of this is that pages using the masterpage do **NOT** have to implement the `<asp:Content>`, so you don't have update them all... only the ones you need.

Comment: Not a problem - these things are not always obvious until pointed out.  Good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: An additional thing to note with contentplaceholders is that they can contain elements within the masterpage itself.  Pages which do not implement the corresponding content element will get those masterpage elements... but pages which DO implement them can override with whatever they want